# Construction of the integers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I know the typical method for constructing the set of integers as the set of equivalence classes on the relation (a,b)~(c,d) such that a+d=c+b, I was wondering why we don't use something like

$\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}^-\cup\mathbb{N}$

where

$\mathbb{Z}^-=\{z:(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}-\{\emptyset\})(\exists! z)(z+n=0)\}$

I'm still relatively new to set theory, so I'm having trouble seeing problems with this, but if I had to make a guess, it would be that it requires the members to explicitly be negative integers, which haven't yet been defined. Or maybe it is because it depends on a definition of addition between integers and naturals which can't be defined until we've properly defined the integers. Can anyone tell me if I would be right about either of these or lead me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you know that $\mathbb{Z}^{-}$ is not empty?

Comment: Doesn't this go back to my first idea of why it isn't done? It relies on an explicit mention of the negatives which we don't know if they exist yet and therefore can't say whether or not the set is empty.

Comment: Ay. There is the rub.

Comment: You can use the device of [making a disjoint copy of the set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)  $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, and you can also 'rename' the elements,

$\quad \Bbb N_{\text{copy}} = \{-0,-1,-2\dots\}$

You don't need $-0$, so set 

$\quad \Bbb Z =  \Bbb N_{\text{copy}} \setminus \{-0\} \sqcup \Bbb N$

$\quad$Now you only have to define the binary operation of addition $+$. A difficulty, if you proceed without bringing in a bit of nuance,  will be proving that  $+$ is associative.

Answer (score 0):

One could well constrcut a set $\mathbb{Z^-}$ of negative integers in whichever reasonable way one likes and claim that an integer is anything which is either a positive natural number, zero, or a negetive integer. In other words, $n$ is an integers iff $n\in\mathbb{Z}:=\mathbb{N}\cup\mathbb{Z^-}$.

The reason why we don't follow this path is that if we did so, the rules for adding and multiplying
integers would split into many different cases (e.g., negative times positive equals positive; negative plus positive is either negative, positive,
or zero, depending on which term is larger, etc.) and to verify all the
properties would end up being much messier.